# How to create MSA Id & Password for creating Azure Bot service using SDK

Tags: .net, azure, azure-bot-service

I want to create dynamically Azure bot services based on data.
For creating Bot service I have used **Microsoft.Azure.Management.BotService** NuGet package.

For creating but I need to enter MSA App Id as well as password.
Currently, I am creating manually from https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/#/appList 
But is there any way to create this App dynamically and obtain Id/Passwords?

```
// Create Bot client
AzureBotServiceClient botServiceClient = new AzureBotServiceClient(credentials);
botServiceClient.TenantId = credentials.TenantId;
botServiceClient.SubscriptionId = credentials.DefaultSubscriptionId;

// Create Bot 
Bot bot = new Bot
{
    Location = "centralus",
    Properties = new BotProperties
    {
        Description = "Description of New Bot",
        DisplayName = "MyNewBotCreatedFromConsole",
        Endpoint = "https://xyz.azurewebsites.net/api/Messages",
        Kind = "sdk",
        Sku = new Sku(SkuName.F0, SkuTier.Free),
        Location = "centralus",
        MsaAppId = "???",
        MsaAppPassword = "???"
    },
};
botServiceClient.Bots.Create(resourceName, resourceName, bot);
```

Note: This package already contains **GetOrCreateMsaAppId()** but it was private

Answer (score 2):

> How to create MSA Id & Password for creating Azure Bot service using SDK

If you want to create Azure AD application
and Rest API is acceptable, you could use Microsoft graph [create application API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/application_post_applications).

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications
```

> Important: APIs under the /beta version in Microsoft Graph are in preview and are subject to change. Use of these APIs in production applications is not supported.

I test it with [Microsoft Graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer), it works correctly for me.

**Request body format**

```
{
  "allowPublicClient": true,
  "displayName": "tomsdk",
  passwordCredentials:
  [{
  "customKeyIdentifier": null,
  "endDateTime": "2019-07-01T00:00:00Z",
  "keyId": "b5b2920e-a47c-43b7-91ef-25ae96fddddd", //Guid
  "startDateTime": "2018-07-01T00:00:00Z",
  "secretText": "123QWER!@#$qwweerzcxvc", //password, you could set it by yourself.
  "hint": "string"
}]
}
```

**Test result:**

[image]

Comment: Hi @Tom Sun, I need to use SDK for same. I have tried Microsoft.Graph SDK for that but unable to find its class/method for that. Is it is possible via SDK?

Comment: We could use the Azure [Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient/) to create Azure AD V1 Application. But bot framework needs Azure AD V2 application default. I'm not sure whether v1 application works for bot or not. Currently, it seems that there is no related SDK to create to Azure AD v2 application.

Comment: @TomSun I wasn't able to replicate these results. There are any other steps necessary? I've linked the my Azure account in the Graph Explorer but I get a 200 back, and a payload with only the odata.context field.

Answer (score 0):

Just for everyone's awareness that comes across this in the future. This is **no longer allowed**. They have changed how you add/remove password credentials of an application.

You can not add the `passwordCredentials: []`directectly to the application creation `POST` call. You'll get the error similar to this: `New password credentials must be generated using service actions.` You have to first create the application and then making a `POST` call to update the application's `passwordCredentials` field. With this change you cannot generate your own secret text anymore. You can only set the start date, end date, and displayname.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-addpassword?view=graph-rest-beta